# queued-work-looper Thread made when Handler posts a Runnable on main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to understand threading in Android. 
So this is the code that I have -

```
   private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
   private Runnable mPeriodicUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(THREAD_MAX_PRIORITY);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mPeriodicUpdate, 10*1000 - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()%1000);
        mIsStarted = true;
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "Lat: " + mLatitude + "\nLng: " + mLongitude,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "run: Getting Location Information");
    }
};
```

When I am calling  `mHandler.post(mPeriodicUpdate);` a new thread pops up (see image).

[image]

I want to know what this thread is about? If I suspend this thread, the Toasts keep appearing. When I suspend main thread though, the Toasts stop as well as Log messages. Evidently, this is running on main thread, then what is this new thread for?

Comment: I don't see this thread when running your code

Comment: By my understanding, `handler.post(Runnable)` this adds the runnable as a message to message queue, and the runnable will be executed on main thread. So `handler.post` won't create new thread

Comment: In `QueuedWorker.java#getHandler()`, it has `HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("queued-work-looper",
                        Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND);
                handlerThread.start();` So the thread was probably created from here. And the document says: ` * This was created for writing SharedPreference edits out asynchronously so we'd have a mechanism
 * to wait for the writes in Activity.onPause and similar places, but we may use this mechanism for
 * other things in the future.` Do you have SharedPreference operations in your code?

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO.Oh yes I am using SharedPreferences. But that is used in different class. I tried again by commenting out SharedPreference operation, even though it was in other class. Still that thread popping up. But you gave me bit of an insight. I would like to add, this code is inside a Service.